# VB.NET Export Checked DataGridView Rows to CSV

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, export-to-csv

I have a DataGridView with a CheckBox column in column 10. I want to export all checked rows to a CSV file. The following code exports all rows in the DataGridView regardless if the rows are checked or not. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

```
        Dim RowNumB As Integer
        Dim rows = From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
                   Where Not row.IsNewRow
                   Select Array.ConvertAll(row.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).ToArray, Function(c) If(c.Value IsNot Nothing, c.Value.ToString, ""))
        Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(Path)
            For Each r In rows
                RowNumB = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
                If DataGridView1.Item(10, RowNumB).Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso DataGridView1.Item(10, RowNumB).Value = 1 Then
                    sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", r))
                End If
            Next
        End Using
```

Comment: What is the point of this: `DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index`? That value won't change in this procedure. You've already converted all fields to an array of `String()`, just check the last string in the array, to see what its value is, no need to get the value from the DataGridView again (using the wrong Row index). -- You should mention whether the CheckBox Column is `ThreeState` or simple. -- You should also set `Option Strict ON`. -- Are all those conversions to string actually producing the expected results, without any specialized formatting?

Comment: The checkbox column is not ThreeState. I’ve set the underlying values as 0 and 1 for True and False. 
The conversion to string are producing the desired results, just not eliminating the rows that are not checked. I’m not sure how to check the last string in the array as you have suggested. Could you please help with this?

Comment: After a bit more playing around with the code I have found the solution, thanks to @Jimi for giving me the idea. I revised a line to this `If r(10) IsNot Nothing AndAlso r(10).ToString = "1" Then`. 
I also removed the `RowNumB = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index` line.

Comment: This would probably have been a lot easier if the DGV had been bound to a DataTable..

Comment: ps, there's occasionally a bit more to creating a CSV than "stringjoin an array with a comma and write it to a file"..